# CSS Z-index for second row of Horizontal Navigation

Tags: fixed, css

I have a horizontal navigation bar which I'm playing around with; the idea is fairly simple and certainly not new; hover on the top row and an appropriate sub-menu appears beneath. Both levels are shown horizontally.

What I want to do is have a top-border on the sub-menu which 'loops' above the parent item. So far, I've added a border to the top, left & right of the parent `<a>` and also a top border to the sub-menu `<ul>`, but I can't hide the sub-menu top border when it is below the parent item.

I've tried adjusting the margin of the sub-menu to move it up by a pixel (the border width) and then adjust the `z-index` of the parent in an attempt to place it above, but with no success. Any help would be appreciated, fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wright_jamie/XYegy/).

Answer (score 0):

Your links are stting on the baseline. drop them on bottom or top vertical-align, so the gap underneath goes:

http://jsfiddle.net/XYegy/1/

```
#menu967>ul>li>a {
    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem - the border between the bottom of the `li:hover` in the top row of the menu and the `.sub-menu` is shown. I want this to disapear so that I get own continuous line that loops over the parent `li`.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to achieve what I want using a combination of negative `margin` and a negative `z-index` on the sub-menu.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wright_jamie/GLrGs/1/)